# Alternative to Without further ado?

Tags: terminology, expression-choice

It's a cliche talk in nearly all public speaking events, regardless of the type of the gathering (academic, business, wedding) and the level/class (*top* League school, fortune 500 company, 200 bucks start up).

Are there better one liners to express the same in a decent manner?

Comment: So, you're asking, in essence: after speaking about the next speaker, i.e. introducing him to the audience, describing his qualities, qualifications, and quietism, you want a phrase that stands in for "without keeping you waiting any longer", is that correct?

Comment: Certainly! You described it well.

Comment: @aspiring What do liners mean? I cannot find the meaning in the dictionaries. If it is a mistake, then it should be corrected.

Comment: @Amande: A "one liner" is a statement in a single sentence that doesn't need further clarification (i.e. a terse and yet complete expression), however, it's most commonly used to refer to "one line jokes". Mitch Hedberg was a very successful one liner comedian, some source material can be found here: http://thoughtcatalog.com/christopher-hudspeth/2013/08/50-hilarious-brilliant-mitch-hedberg-one-liners-that-wouldve-made-epic-tweets/

Comment: @Flater spot on! Amande, please [check here for oxford dictionary reference on *one-liner*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/one-liner).

Comment: Ah, ok, this is a one-liner, not a liner. I did a wrong search. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'll go with David Sedaris, and offer *Live For Your Listening Pleasure*...

Comment: Yours is alright really. But I was thinking if there are more responses.

Comment: Mine is tongue-in-cheek. I hope someone else answers, too. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you've already completed the guest's summary biography, excerpted encomiums, etc., etc., there's no reason you can't move on immediately to

> So now, please welcome ...

Answer (score -2):

Delay aside = alternative to "without further ado"

Comment: I don't recognise this expression, Joasnda. Please add supporting evidence.